# Is it possible to get rid of admin new updates notifications?

Tags: admin

I am doing projects for clients and sometimes an update messes a lot. So, can we leave error messages and get rid of new updates notifications in wordpress admin side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://www.vooshthemes.com/blog/wordpress-tip/wordpress-quick-tip-remove-the-dashboard-update-message/ which seems to work good for 2.9- versions

```
//Copied from the above referenced article
remove_action('wp_version_check', 'wp_version_check');
remove_action('admin_init', '_maybe_update_core');
add_filter('pre_transient_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;"));
```

For 2.9+ try this: http://www.wpinsite.com/code-snippets/remove-wordpress-dashboard-update-notification-message/

```
add_action('admin_menu','foo_hide_update');
function foo_hide_update() {
    remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
}
```